# Why isn't my collection.upsert() query NOT setting multiple parameters to the collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, upsert

I have an `collection.upsert()` function in my Meteor method. For some strange reason it only seems to upsert the first parameter, and ignores to upsert the rest of the parameters. Can someone kindly explain why this is happening?

Find below the events template, where the `userId, password, email, names,` parameters are passed onto the Meteor method `regenerateApiKey` in subject

**/client/main.js**

```
Template.apiKey.events({
  'click .regenerate-api-key': function( ){

   var userId = Meteor.userId(); 
   var password = Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken;
   var email = Meteor.user().services.google.email;
   var names = Meteor.user().services.google.name;

   alert("Password: " +password);
   alert("email: " +email);
   alert("email: " +names);     

   confirmRegeneration = confirm( "Are you sure? This will invalidate your current key!" );

     if ( confirmRegeneration ) {
       Meteor.call( "regenerateApiKey", userId, password, email, names, function( error, response ) {
         if ( error ) {
           alert( error.reason, "danger" );
         } else {
  +response );
           alert( "All done! You have a new API key: " +response );
           console.log("Response is: " +response);
         }
       });
     }
  }
});
```

The events template above renders 5 popup Alerts:

POPUP.1 `Password: ya29.Glz`

POPUP.2 `email: centos.east@gmail.com`

POPUP.3 `email: Centos East`

POPUP.4 `Are you sure? This will invalidate your current key!`

To which I press YES

POPUP.5 `All done! You have a new API key: [object Object]`

The code below illustrates the `Meteor.call( "regenerateApiKey")` along with the `userId, password, email, names` parameters.

**/server/main.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  regenerateApiKey: function( userId, password, email, names ){
    check( userId, Meteor.userId() );

    var newKey = Random.hexString( 32 );
    var password = password;
    var email = email;
    var names = names;

    console.log("password: " +password);
    console.log("email: " +email);
    console.log("names: " +names );
    console.log("newKey: " +newKey);

    try {
      var keyId = APIKeys.upsert( { "owner": userId }, {
        $set: {
          "key": newKey,
          "password": password, 
          "email": email, 
          "names": names
        }
      });

      return keyId;
    } catch(exception) {
        console.log("FAILED UPDATE")
      return exception;
    }
  }
});
```

In the terminal, I am able to see what is rendered by the code above:

```
password: ya29.Glz

email: centos.east@gmail.com

names: Cent East

newKey : 337829bb18082690a32f94a3c23b3782
```

When I query `APIKeys.find().fetch()` in the console, I get:

```
key: "337829bb18082690a32f94a3c23b3782"
_id:"PgBmn6zSYiXTbx6tu"
```

Which indicates that ONLY the `newKey` variable was `set` to `key` BUT the query ignored to set `password`, `email`, and `names` variables.

Can someone kindly explain why the `password`, `email`, and `names` variables aren't being set (included) in the collection?

Comment: Maybe try : APIKeys.update( { "owner": userId }, {
        $set: {
          "key": newKey,
          "password": password, 
          "email": email, 
          "names": names
        }
      , { upsert: true});

Comment: when you say you check from the console is it the mongo console or the chrome console ?  If the latest it is maybe than your password, email and names variables are not published to the user.

Comment: Do you have a schema or any before hooks attached to `APIKeys`?

Comment: @Ivo. I tried what you suggested: `   var keyId = APIKeys.update( { "owner": userId }, 
    { 
       $set: {  
       "key": newKey, 
       "password": password, 
       "email": email, 
       "names": names 
      },
    }, 
    { 
     upsert: true
      
    });` But this still gives the same results of only the key is saved into the collection. the password, email and names STILL aren't saved.

Comment: @Ivo Its the Chrome console that I check from. Your explanation about the password, email and names variables not being published to the user would make sense. This might seem like a silly questions but, how do I publish the variables to the user?

Comment: @Ivo Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. It was indeed the fact that I omitted to publish the rest of the variables (being: password, email, names ) apart from key. The rest of your following this thread look at Answer Your Own Question for clarification on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why only the key was being `upsert` in the query below:

```
APIKeys.upsert( { "owner": userId }, {
        $set: {
          "key": newKey,
          "password": password, 
          "email": email, 
          "names": names
        }
      });
```

was actually false. The ENTIRE query was correctly being carried out. 
The fault was in the Publish configuration itself!

The publish configuration ONLY allowed for the **key** `fields` value to be displayed! 
Find below my Publish configuration code:

```
Meteor.publish( 'APIKey', function(){
  var user = this.userId;
  var data = APIKeys.find( { "owner": user }, {fields: 
                                                    {  
                                                      "key": true, 
                                                    } });


  if ( data ) {
        return data;
  }

  return this.ready();
});
```

To correct this issue, I have had to re-configure my publish to the below code:

```
Meteor.publish( 'APIKey', function(){
  var user = this.userId;
  var data = APIKeys.find( { "owner": user }, {fields: 
                                                    {  
                                                      "key": true, 
                                                      "password": true,
                                                      "email": true,
                                                      "names": true

                                                    } });


  if ( data ) {
     return data;
  }

  return this.ready();
});
```

I'd like to thank @Ivo in the thread for pointing me in the right direction in regards to this issue.